# How to rewrite a URL without leaving the current page in C#?

Tags: c#, url-rewriting

I want to Re-write my URL without leaving the current.
I find large number of post related to URL Re-writing, but i did'n get success.

I want if user enter this URL -

```
http://localhost:16185/Company/CareerWebsite.aspx?org_name=hire-people
```

URL automatically convert into this format -

```
http://localhost:16185/hire-people
```

but the original page (`Company/CareerWebsite.aspx?org_name=hire-people`) does not leave.

Means, user did't see the original URL(`Company/CareerWebsite.aspx?org_name=hire-people`) in browser. User can only see virtual URL like `/hire-people`.

Thanks for help...!!!

Comment: While @Sergio answer will put you on the right track it misses the main rule that will rewrite the url. But it can only be written if you define a bit more the rules you want to have. I can hardly imagine that every url asked will use `Company/CareerWebsite.aspx` to provide the content and the same way I don't think you want to only rewrite `http://localhost:16185/hire-people`

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to do it directly same way as you described you need to do `Redirect 301 or 302`. For url-rewriting you'l probably need to install `urlRewrite` module for iis. 
So far you'l need some kind of following url-rewrite rule in web.config file:

```
<rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^Company/CareerWebsite\.aspx$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^org_name=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```